# Schedule with primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying do the example of this page:
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/schedule.jsf

I have the xhtml page like:, that is the same that in the example, but i call the page: index.xhtml:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:form id="form">

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule">

            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
            <p:ajax event="eventSelect" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show()" />
            <p:ajax event="eventMove" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventMove}" update="messages" />
            <p:ajax event="eventResize" listener="#{scheduleController.onEventResize}" update="messages" />

        </p:schedule>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
            <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="title" value="Title:" />
                <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleController.event.title}" required="true"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
                <p:inputMask id="from" value="#{scheduleController.event.startDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                </p:inputMask>

                <h:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
                <p:inputMask id="to" value="#{scheduleController.event.endDate}" mask="99/99/9999">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                </p:inputMask>

                <h:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleController.event.allDay}" />

                <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
                <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleController.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>

    </h:form>
</html>
```

And now i have in the Java class:

```
public class ScheduleController implements Serializable {

private ScheduleModel eventModel;
private ScheduleEvent event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

public ScheduleController() {
    eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Champions League Match", previousDay8Pm(), previousDay11Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Birthday Party", today1Pm(), today6Pm()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Breakfast at Tiffanys", nextDay9Am(), nextDay11Am()));
    eventModel.addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Plant the new garden stuff", theDayAfter3Pm(), fourDaysLater3pm()));
}

public Date getRandomDate(Date base) {
    Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
    date.setTime(base);
    date.add(Calendar.DATE, ((int) (Math.random()*30)) + 1);    //set random day of month

    return date.getTime();
}


public Date getInitialDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), Calendar.FEBRUARY, calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

    return calendar.getTime();
}

public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
    return eventModel;
}

private Calendar today() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DATE), 0, 0, 0);

    return calendar;
}


    private Date previousDay8Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date previousDay11Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date today1Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date theDayAfter3Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 2);     
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date today6Pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 6);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date nextDay9Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 9);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date nextDay11Am() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone();
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 1);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 11);

    return t.getTime();
}

private Date fourDaysLater3pm() {
    Calendar t = (Calendar) today().clone(); 
    t.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
    t.set(Calendar.DATE, t.get(Calendar.DATE) + 4);
    t.set(Calendar.HOUR, 3);

    return t.getTime();
}

    public ScheduleEvent getEvent() {
    return event;
}

public void setEvent(ScheduleEvent event) {
    this.event = event;
}

public void addEvent(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    if(event.getId() == null)
        eventModel.addEvent(event);
    else
        eventModel.updateEvent(event);

    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();
}

public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
}

public void onDateSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
    event = new DefaultScheduleEvent("", (Date) selectEvent.getObject(), (Date) selectEvent.getObject());
}

public void onEventMove(ScheduleEntryMoveEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event moved", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

public void onEventResize(ScheduleEntryResizeEvent event) {
    FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Event resized", "Day delta:" + event.getDayDelta() + ", Minute delta:" + event.getMinuteDelta());

    addMessage(message);
}

private void addMessage(FacesMessage message) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}

}
```

That is the same too, that in the example in the page of primefaces.

But the problem is that when i run the project my index.xhtml page is empry, not appear the schedule, and i do not know what happen?

If somebody can help me,

thanks

My Web xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And my Faces-config.xml is:

```
<faces-config version="1.2" 

    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"

    xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd">

<managed-bean>
  <description>UsernName Bean</description>
  <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>demo.user</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
     <property-name>name</property-name>
     <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
     <value/>
  </managed-property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I have your web.xml file So that did configure

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> /.Important here
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern> /.Important here
</servlet-mapping>
```

You have not mention the above code and your are trying to use .xhtml or .jsf
If u have used .xhtml to show the page it wont show use .jsf it will work fine

Comment: that means that url is not proper. What is the url ?

Answer (score 0):

You must add the following annotation **@ManagedBean (name = "scheduleController")** before the ScheduleController class definition and you don't need to add it in the faces-config.xml because you work on jsf2.
This annotation must be imported from 'javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean'.

Good luck.